# How do I right align text in an access text field?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I know this sounds like a simple question that should have a simple solution. However, I am having the hardest time getting text to fully right align. Whenever I change the "text align" setting to "right," there is always a little bit of padding between the text and the edge of the cell/field. I have set the margin and padding values to zero as well as looked at the form in form view and datasheet view (datasheet view is how the form is used) Another odd thing is that when I left align the fields, the text is right up against the left edge of the cell/field; just like what I want on the right.

[image: Here is an example of what I am seeing.]

Does anyone have any advice? I have never had this issue before and can't seem to find any other place on the web where this issue has been discussed. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the `Format` property of the field is set to "Currency". If so, try changing it to "Fixed" or "General Number" to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Gord Thompson. You lead me in the right direction. I couldn't use the currency format because we have our own custom formatting: "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00[Red]);0;0" However, for some reason I decided to remove the zero-value and undefined value formats: the last two zeros. This left a string of "#,##0.00;(#,##0.00[Red])." After that the data aligned just fine. I use that formatting string in other sections of the database and have the text right aligned just fine. I guess I can only chock this up to a unique circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an interesting solution to a related matter.  How to move a left justified dates away from the left margin?  Padding the date format is one way to achieve this.  Here is the field in one of my queries where the date includes minutes and I want it shortened to `mm/dd/yy` and not left justified.  This sort of does it...

```
Date: Format(Int([Transactions.UpdateDate]),"   mm/dd/yy")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This would work well if you posted the question that this answers and then posted this as an answer to that question. Here it is not an answer to the question that it is attached to. You stand a better chance deleting this and creating a separate question and then putting this answer there.